Check if anything has been entered into the input React element
I have the following Input component:
import { useRef } from 'react';
import classes from './styles/Input.module.css';

function Input({ children, inputID = "default", iconSrc = "icons/person.svg", hasIcon = false }) {
    const input = useRef(null);
    const placeholder = useRef(null);

    function animatedPlaceholder() {
        if (document.activeElement === input.current) {
            placeholder.current.classList.add(classes['input-text-placeholder-up']);
            return;
        }
        placeholder.current.classList.remove(classes['input-text-placeholder-up']);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes["input-text-container"]}>
                {hasIcon ? <img className={classes['input-text-icon']} src={iconSrc} onClick={() => input.current.focus() } /> : ''}
                <input
                    ref={input}
                    className={
                        [
                            classes['input-text'],
                            hasIcon ? classes['with-icon'] : '',
                        ].join(' ')
                    }
                    type="text"
                    id={inputID}
                    onFocus={animatedPlaceholder}
                    onBlur={animatedPlaceholder}
                />
                <div
                    ref={placeholder}
                    className={
                        [
                            classes['input-text-placeholder'],
                            hasIcon ? classes['placeholder-with-icon'] : '',
                        ].join(' ')
                    }
                >
                    {children}
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Input;

I wanted to make a simple animation for a div element that acts as a placeholder, and to do this I dynamically add the input-text-placeholder-up class to it. However, I need the class to remain even if the input element loses focus but some text has been entered into it. I would of course like to do this without useState, as I wanted to collect form data using the new hooks that React 19 provides, and do it in a different component. Is it possible to do this without useState, or is there no other way?
